# Gitlab: create new user via API - 404

Tags: api, gitlab

I am trying to create new user using gitlab API v3.

Gitlab API docs: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/users.md#user-creation

I am sending POST request to mygitlabhost/api/v3/users/ with all required data: email=losddsd@gmail.com&password=33wrwsdfsf3&username=testone&name=fuuu and it returns me 404.
Acutally I can list all users via GET request to mygitlabhost/api/v3/users/ so API seems to be running.

Request details: http://imm.io/120o6

what am I wrong?

Comment: The is a similar issue (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3411), but not relevant for your case: you haven't set a relative path for your GitLab server.

Comment: Have a look into Gitlabs logs.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [issue 3411 "unable to add users to team"](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3411) has some workaround in place for:

- Apache
  Add this to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

```
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8085/gitlab/api
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8085/gitlab/api
```

- NGinX

```
location /api {
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
  proxy_pass http://gitlab-sock/gitlab/api;
  proxy_redirect default;
}
```

> To fix this problem you can modify the file: [`app/assets/javascripts/api.js.coffee`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/api.js.coffee#L1-L4) to match your setup.
>
> In our case the path has gitlab as prefix:

```
users_path: "/gitlab/api/:version/users.json"
user_path: "/gitlab/api/:version/users/:id.json"
notes_path: "/gitlab/api/:version/projects/:id/notes.json"
```